# Get property of List<StorageFile>

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make playlist for my mediaplayer. I have a List and need to get names it contains and set it to the Listbox on mainwindow. I have code, but it just set items to Windows.Storage.StorageFile.

```
PlaylistBox.ItemsSource = Playlist;
```

upd. i have listbox on my wpf form, i need to fill it with members of

```
List<StorageFile>.DisplayName
```

but all i have is objects Windows.Storage.StorageFile

Comment: What is the problem exactly yura ? You are not able to bind it ?

Comment: Yura can you please add more information?

Comment: MSDN is your friend https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the DisplayMemberPath property on your PlaylistBox

```
    <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" x:Name="PlaylistBox" />
```

Or you can bind to the list of names

```
PlaylistBox.ItemsSource = Playlist.Select(p=>p.DisplayName).ToList();
```

Or you can specify ItemTemplate

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding DisplayName}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```